# How to configure Proxy.cgi with IIS

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, proxy

I installed GeoServer on server 172.20.100.13 and i also publish my OpenLayers application on same server. when i make the request to this server for accessing the page like, (http://172.20.100.13/Myapp/layers.aspx), then WMS and WFS Layers does not display over Google Map. But the same application with geoserver installed on localhost works fine.

As i understand from different forums, I need to configure Proxy.cgi with IIS to fix this problem and then use it as: 
Openlayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.py?url"

I want to know, Am i right or wrong in my understanding OR i am making a mistake.

If i am right, Then can anybody please tell me how i configure Proxy.cgi with IIS ?  If some usefuk link available to fix this, then it will be very good for me.

Comment: Where i have to put this files in my website ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With IIS I suggest to use this stuff, instead of configure CGI: http://code.google.com/p/iisproxy/issues/detail?id=8

Disclaimer: I suggest this simply because It's not so simple to use CGI&Python inside IIS.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a goog idea set up a proxy. The right solution is to add a specific header to the http response of Geoserver, to allow cross domains request. If you run Geoserver using Jetty, use the following links

1. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303162/jetty-cross-origin-filter

*EDIT why using a proxy is a bad idea*

I see some points against the use of a proxy (both script or configuration like mod_proxy):

1. Security: 90% of the times, the proxy is not restricted to allow only a specific list of hosts. Developers never put the right effort to secure this stuff. If you spend 15 minutes on google searching for "proxy.php?url" or something else, you will find a lot of scripts that can be used as openproxy (one is here http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/class_http/proxy.phps, just tak out the s)
2. It's a big waste of time to setup every time for every application a proxy! If you "fix" the server, you will be good forever! (Ok, maybe I am the only one who works on hundreds of project a day :P

Comment: Please explain why it is not a good idea to set up a proxy.