# How to access both IIS and Geoserver at port 80 from outside the production environment?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

At production server, IIS and GeoServer are installed. I can access IIS at port 80 From out side the production environment. i also want to access GeoServer at the same port 80 from out side of production environment, Like http://92.108.64.13:80/geoserver/web/.
But, i could not access GeoServer at port 80.

Is it possible to access both IIS and Geoserver at port 80 ? Actually I do not want to open any other port for accessing GeoServer. Is there any solution available for accessing both Geoserver and IIS at port 80 ?

need for useful suggestion for solving this problem

Comment: You ought to start accepting some of the answers you've been given for your questions. See here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq if you're unsure what that means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set up a proxy under IIS - see [How to configure Proxy.cgi with IIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/how-to-configure-proxy-cgi-with-iis) or google geoserver iis for more discussions.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to iant use a proxy.

or you can install **Tomcat 6.0.3** (7 has issues with geoserver)

then edit
 tomcat/conf/server.xml file -
set the proxy in the file

set incoming traffic routed to localhost:80

Edit the Inbound Rule in IIS

See
http://cartoninjas.pl/post/2011/02/01/GeoServer-production-environment-on-Windows-Server-with-IIS-and-Apache.aspx
for full details

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented this. All you need to do is install the Application Request Routing module and the URL rewrite module on IIS. Then create a rule in URL rewrite to direct all geoserver calls from IIS to your java container port. e.g. you can refer to "/geoserver/wms" in your open layers code but URL rewrite rule can redirect this to "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms" (assuming port 8080 runs geoserver).

Comment: Hi Dhananjay, welcome to GIS.se and thank you for contributing! Who is "we"? (please edit answer and link to or define who you are speaking for. It will help people looking for more information.)